# How to save decoded raw rgba frames using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to transcode mp4 video to a raw video frames stored in a file.
I'm trying this command but it fails with `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'test.rgba'`:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba -an test.rgba
```

Answer (score 2):

It's this

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf format=rgba -f rawvideo test.rgba
```